# Objective-C multiple inheritance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have 2 classes one includes methodA and the other include methodB. So in a new class I need to override the methods methodA and methodB. So how do I achieve multiple inheritance in objective C? I am little bit confused with the syntax.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't support multiple inheritance, and you don't need it.  Use composition:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
}

-(void)methodA;

@end

@interface ClassB : NSObject {
}

-(void)methodB;

@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
  ClassA *a;
  ClassB *b;
}

-(id)initWithA:(ClassA *)anA b:(ClassB *)aB;

-(void)methodA;
-(void)methodB;

@end
```

Now you just need to invoke the method on the relevant ivar.  It's more code, but there just isn't multiple inheritance as a language feature in objective-C.

Comment: Composition is very often a better approach to take than inheritance, especially if you do much unit testing on the code.  It affords much more flexibility in that you can easily swap out the implementations without redefining the class itself.  Particularly handy when you want to, say, swap ClassA and ClassB for mock objects.  Even at runtime swapping out implementations (e.g. FTPFileStore vs LocalFileStore) becomes cleaner with composition.  That doesn't mean inheritance doesn't have it's place though, but the need for multiple inheritance would suggest that I re-think my design ;)

Comment: I don't understand this. Don't you need to instantiate `ClassA` and `ClassB`? Does calling `methodA:` on `MyClass` somehow automatically call `methodA:` on `ClassA`?

Comment: No, but you can still share the behaviour through message-passing, the way OOP was originally supposed to work. If you don't immediately jump to thinking you need inheritance and instead consider a solution using composition, you'll find you start structuring your programs in a more maintainable way. Of course ObjC has basic inheritance for the cases where it is correct to use it.

Comment: see this @dllwtq
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_inheritance.htm

Comment: d11wtq, great answer!  As an addition, message forwarding allows you to skip the step of re-implementing methodA and methodB.  Messages can be automatically forwarded to appropriate objects with just a little work.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html

Comment: @ashokdy: there are too many errors in the referenced article: it talks about obj-c having Multiple inheritance, its example on the second page asks us to 'Consider a base class Shape and its derived class Rectangle as follows' but the example is about Person and Employee.

Comment: I don't see why you need to include:
    -(void)methodA;
    -(void)methodB;
 Because wouldn't you just invoke them  on the class A when needed and then on class B when needed, and add them as Properties?  I would think this would be a better approach, seeing as, one of the benefits of subclassing is NOT having to put the method declaration in the subClass.

Comment: Composition is very handy!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I code singletonPattern as "a parent" Basically I used a combination of protocol and category.

The only thing I cannot add is a new "ivar" however, I can push it with associated object.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@protocol BGSuperSingleton
+(id) singleton1;
+(instancetype)singleton;
@end

@interface NSObject (singleton) <BGSuperSingleton>

@end

static NSMutableDictionary * allTheSingletons;

+(instancetype)singleton
{
    return [self singleton1];
}
+(id) singleton1
{
    NSString* className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);

    if (!allTheSingletons)
    {
        allTheSingletons = NSMutableDictionary.dictionary;
    }

    id result = allTheSingletons[className];

    //PO(result);
    if (result==nil)
    {
        result = [[[self class] alloc]init];
        allTheSingletons[className]=result;
        [result additionalInitialization];
    }
    return result;
}

-(void) additionalInitialization
{

}
```

Whenever I want a class to "inherit" this BGSuperSingleton I just do:

```
#import "NSObject+singleton.h"
```

and add `@interface MyNewClass () <BGSuperSingleton>`

Comment: Categories are not multiple inheritance. They're a way of tacking on methods/functions to an already existing class.

Multiple inheritance allows a third class to be a combination of one OR MORE classes (including variables).

I like categories. Categories are very useful. But they are NOT multiple inheritance.

Comment: But a subclass of UIViewController can also "support", in this case, singleton pattern should I wish.

Comment: Technically all NSManagedObject "can now call" [obj singleton]. I set those I wish with support of the protocol. As good as multiple inheritance in anyway. This is only if I want to the child class to support both the interface and implementation of the parent. If only the implementation then obviously composition is the way to go.

Comment: Just adding the protocol like <BGSuperSingleton> does not make the classes then be able to call the "singleton" method. You still have to implement it...

Answer (score -4):

Do you know about Protocols, protocols is the way to implement the multiple inheritance

Comment: +1 "To capture similarities among classes that are not hierarchically related." https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html

Comment: In this case, where both methods will be overridden, protocols will do the trick. In other cases when you want to use inheritance to reuse code, protocols would not help. However this can usually be solved by letting the classes superclasses inherit from each other, or by combining them, there is usually a way to get it right if a subclass actually share code with 2 classes.

Comment: you can combine protocol with either a category or composition.

Comment: -1 because Protocols are not there for multiple inheritance at all. Similarly in `JAVA` , `Interfaces` are not to provide or mimic multiple inheritance.

Comment: Protocols do have the benefit of allowing you to let Objective C runtime know that something responds to a given selector and to make the compiler prevent you from failing to implement a callback method that needs to be there for things to work correctly—without having to depend on (i.e. import/include) whatever's on the other side of the protocol. They are basically a thin facade that doesn't even exist :D

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer From Apple's own [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html) *A protocol declares a programmatic interface that any class may choose to implement. Protocols make it possible for two classes distantly related by inheritance to communicate with each other to accomplish a certain goal. They thus offer an **alternative to subclassing***. As you can see **Apple is**  explicitly using subclassing ie inheriting. Perhaps Nikesh including this in his own answer would be helpful to clarify his argument