# Multiple inheritance in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192203/objective-c-multiple-inheritance)

I want to implement multiple inheritance in Objective-C
i.e. I have a class "Sub" which needs to be a sublass of class "Super" as well as UITableViewController

How can I acheive the same in Obj-C?

Answer (score 22):

Objective-C doesn't support multiple inheritance. You could use a protocol, composition and message forwarding to achieve the same result.

A protocol defines a set of methods that an object must implement (it's possible to have optional methods too). Composition is basically the technique of include a reference to another object and calling that object when it's functionality is required. Message forwarding is a mechanism that allows objects to pass messages onto other objects, for example, an object that is included via composition.

Apple Reference:

- [Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html)
- [Composition](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW15)
- [Message Forwarding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) (and specifically [Forwarding and Multiple Inheritance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH105-SW10))

Comment: This is a good idea !

Answer (score 5):

There is no multiple inheritance in Objective-C. You can try to resolve what you need to with composition though.

Something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    Sub *mySubComponent;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Sub *mySubComponent;
// you can write wrapper methods here to call mySubComponent methods/messages
```