# Inheritance from two different classes objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a class A with textField1, class B with textField2.

i want to use textField1 and textField2 in class C. What i have to import or what i have to do. I think i am straggling with importing files. i.e. #include or something

Thanks for reply in advance.

Comment: See this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192203/objective-c-multiple-inheritance

Comment: do you really need inheritance here or you just need to access textField1 and textField2 from your class C?

Comment: @Maggie i need to access values in  textField1 and textField2 from both classes in my class C label. Nothing else.

Comment: use composition instead. http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinhP.html

Comment: Can anyone suggest me how can i use composition to access values in the textField1 and textField2 in class C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective does not support multiple inheritance. 
You can only inherit from one class, you could use a protocol to make the class match class B.

Comment: Ok that is fine. But how can i use protocol to access textField value of class B in class C. Protocol is used to access methods

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to import both class A and class B in class C, and then access textField1 and textField2. Import syntax is `#import "classA.h"`

Comment: I have tried this mate. But my class C is subclass of class A only, for example the interface of class C says @impliment class C: class A{..}. After importing it does not access textField of class B.

Comment: ok, you didn't state it that way in your question. use @corretge's answer then.

Comment: In that post he deals with methods. i really dont want to do anything with methods. I need to simply access textField VAlues. thats it

Comment: no mate it is not working. I have to access textField values not any method from classA or classB in classC.

Comment: can't you keep a reference of class B in your class C?

Comment: I can use class B's textField in class C with creating object of class  B in C and accessing like b.textField. It shows no error. But it does not show textField value even