# Extending more than one predefined class

Tags: iphone, ios

in my class i want to extend 2 classes from my class.
Here is example

```
@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

}
```

Here am extending `UITableViewCell` like this any other way to extend another class like `UIViewController`......

Any one can suggest me please.

Comment: AFAIK multiple inheritance is not allowed in `Objective-C`

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C does not allow multiple inheritance.

You can use protocols to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As Norvag stated in the comments: `Objective-C` does not support multiple inheritance.

One way to get around this is using *compostion*, see [Objective-C multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192203/objective-c-multiple-inheritance).

But for your case probably most elegant solution would be to creata a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

In this sublass create a property of `UIViewController` type. Add it's view to `cell.contentView`,
make sure you have the frames set up right and you're on your way.