# Can @interface have more than one class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, interface, multiple-inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192203/objective-c-multiple-inheritance)

In my application, I need to add `SideSwipeTableViewController` and `PullRefreshTableViewController` to `ViewController.h`. However, for some reason, it will give me an error when I try to build the app.

Here is the code:

```
@interface ViewController : SideSwipeTableViewController, PullRefreshTableViewController  {

    ...

}
```

It works when either one is in, but not both. What I want to know is: is there a way to successfully implement these two classes? Thanks in advance and my apologies with the question: I'm still a bit new to Objective-C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no multiple inheritance in Objective-C. You can implement any number of protocols though.

Comment: Oh. Well, how would I do that in relation to this?

Comment: Composition, not inheritance. The logic you want can be put into an ivar, for instance.

Comment: @Junior117: that's an entirely separate question, and one that's much broader than you might think at first glance; I'd suggest you take a look at the Protocols section in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html) or look around for more info about protocols.

Comment: @Junior117 you'd use composition rather than inheritance. All of Java, Objective-C and C# reject multiple inheritance for a variety of reasons; Googling those terms should give you quite a lot of material on why.