# GoogleAnalytics in IOS and extend more then two classes?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics, extend

I am trying to implement GoogleAnalytics to my IOS app and come across the following problem: if you want to initialize the tracker in GA to a specific view (lets call it view X), you need to extend class `GAITrackedViewController.h` to the view X.

In my case, I already extend another class in my project and as we all know you can not extend 2 classes. So therefor I wonder, how do I solve this in objective C ? Keep in mind I am not a very experienced programmer and I am also new to objective C.

I will post my `HomeViewController.h` which is being referred as View X example above. As you can see it already extends `MLUIViewController`. If I also want to extend `GAITrackedViewController` to enable GoogleAnalytics, how do I achieve this? / Regards

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface HomeViewController : MLUIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, MLSearchTaskDelegate,  MLDeactivateDelegate>

{
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *menuButton;

IBOutlet UILabel *infoViewTitle;
IBOutlet UIView *infoView;

......................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `MLUIViewController` to inherit from `GAITrackedViewController` and implement `GAITrackedViewController` functionalities in `HomeViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do multiple inheritance.

Check this answer to a similar question: [iphone development: is it possible to extend more than one viewControllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216312/iphone-development-is-it-possible-to-extend-more-than-one-viewcontrollers/14216673#14216673)