# Inheritance In Objective - C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

Okay, so my question itself states what i am asking. 
I have a 3 view controllers. All the three of them are inheriting from a class (MainViewController).
Now what i want to ask is, is it possible in Objective C that suppose I have another class which has some variables and functions which i do not want to include in the MainViewController class, and pass this to one of the ViewControllers.
So if i number my view controllers, and let the other class be SecondClass. 
1st, 2nd and 3rd ViewControllers inherit functions and variables from MainViewController.
If i want 2nd ViewController to inherit SecondClass also, then am i allowed to perform this kind of operation in Objective - C??

Comment: have you tried to use `UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE` flag?

Comment: @holex no I'm kind of a beginner with Objective C, i came up with this problem while learning Controllers so thought of asking.

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C is a single-inheritance language. Each class can inherit from exactly one superclass.

You can work around that with `forwardingTargetForSelector:` if you're absolute desperate but the neater and usually smarter thing is to compose functionality by saying that the second view controller owns an instance of `SecondClass` in addition to being a subclass of `MainViewController`.

You can see an example of Apple doing that in `UIWebView`. It isn't a subclass of `UIScrollView` but it uses a scroll view and exposes that instance (as of iOS 5) for outside actors via a property, `scrollView`.

Comment: Ok, i think I'm able to understand. Thanks.

Comment: And by the way lets note, that exposing your internal implementation as Apple does with UIWebView and it's UIScrollView is a very bad practice.

Comment: @TamásZahola, when you don't understand something it does not mean automatically that is bad. so, I would not say so.

Comment: @holex Then can you please clarify me, why is it OK to expose the fact that the UIWebView uses a UIScrollView as its internal implementation of scrolling behaviour? Can you please also tell me, why is it good, to give up the principle of encapsulation by letting your interface's consumers rely on your implementation's details; forcing the UIWebView to stick with the UIScrollView forever? I guess you think it's also a good thing that the UIWebView has no knowledge of what its UIScrollView might be doing, since direct calls made to the UIScrollView are bypassing the UIWebView entirely!

Comment: @TamásZahola, no matter what I think. your questions are just on wrong basis. the issue is that the `UIWebView` is not a real _view_, it is _controller_ instead. the class's name should reflect that, and I'm pretty sure that misleading name confuses you. please imagine, it is a `UIWebContoller` instead (which is not existing, but that name would reflect much better its purpose), and after you 'put' that class to the _controller-layer_ in your mind, you would understand the whole concept and all your concerns will be irrelevant immediately. I hope it answered you.

Comment: @holex You're saying that it's a controller, OK let's accept this for a moment, because the UIWebView does a bit more than just displaying things like a 'view' should. You say that this justifies exposing implementation details, OK let's accept this too. 
By your logic, the UIStepper is also a 'controller', because it does more than just displaying things: it makes calculations based on its minimumValue, maximumValue, wrap etc. properties. So, because it's a controller, I wonder why Apple decided **not** to expose it's internal parts (UILabels, UIButtons etc. the stepper is composed of) ?

Comment: @holex and by the way, this has nothing to do with controllers/views/models, this is simple object-oriented design. Consider looking up the concept of encapsulation, if you're not familiar w/ this subject.

Comment: @TamásZahola, regarding your answer it's clear to me you don't really know what makes a class _controller_ or _view_. I could explain you, but I don't really have time for hobby developers. therefore, we won't need to debate on it because it'd be pointless, if you can accept it's a kind of _controller_ class, you'll understand why it's been build as is; if you'd not like to accept it, you could argue on it until the time is through but that'd not make too much sense. in practice the class's **functionality** defines a class not their name. if you've a different opinion, please, lecture Apple.

Comment: @holex I hope your teammates will appreciate your misunderstanding of object-oriented principles on your code reviews (however something tells me that you're the kind of iOS developer who puts everything in a 2000-line ViewController, so this shouldn't bother you). Best wishes from a "hobby" developer :)

Comment: @TamásZahola, your arrogance is pathetic, dude. :(

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C does not allow multiple inheritance. Check out this post for a great solution that uses composition.

[Objective-C multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192203/objective-c-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

In objective C there is no support for multiple inheritance. Instead you can use either protocols or categories. 
In addition you can use dynamic typing as well. Check out following link.
http://support.apple.com/kb/TA45894