# Why do you subclass UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, uiview, subclassing

So basically i have been looking of a way to write my code which has alot of uiview instances(makes everything look so messy ! erk!) more readable and elegant.

So far i have seen the use of subclassing but don't really understand the importance/reason of using the practice !

From what i understand:

```
"class2.m":
```

1. You make a class which inherits from the UIView.

   "class1.m":
2. From the superclass "class1" you make an instance of class one which inherits from class2 ?

So what i am trying to understand is that why would you have a class which inherits from a class2.m that inherits from another (UIView), instead of inheriting UIView directly from class1 ?

Sorry i sound like such a stubborn person but i simply just don't get it ? I really want to know why...

Regards

**Edit**

Can someone please explain using an example of something like a class called userProfile and guestProfile that subclasses Profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An analogy is that say a UIView is like an `Animal`, now class1.m is a `bird` and class2.m is a `duck`. a duck is a bird which is an animal (inheritance)

now if we were to make a new `bird`, we dont want to just inherit from `animal` otherwise we will need to recode everything `bird` defines, which just adds code bloat and wastes time.

but say you want to make a dog, we cant obviously inherit from `bird`, because a dog doesnt have any of the features of a `bird`, so we would have to inherit from animal instead.

hope that clarifies things a bit

Comment: Deff the best answer !

Answer (score 3):

The reason I subclass `UIView` is so I can override `-drawRect:` to do my own custom drawing. Because `Core Graphics` drawing code can only be executed from this method, it is only exposed when you subclass, giving me an opportunity to customize my views.

Comment: can you normally do that with initwithframe ?

Answer (score 1):

It's useful if you have several classes (class2, class3, class4...) which inherit from UIView but have something in common. You put the common stuff in class1, and you make these classes inherit from class1.

Comment: @jcarom what is an ideal paradigm please ?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

You subclass `UIView` in order to inherit all the `UIView` functionality and add custom functionality.

**Long answer:**

Your question pertains more to the idea of inheritance than the use of subclassing `UIView` specifically. Inheritance is a simple concept, but can cause confusion if you are new to object oriented programming.

If you notice, all classes that you will commonly use when developing an iOS application inherit from `NSObject`. `NSObject` is the root class of most Objective-C classes, the main class method which NSObject provides (and subsequently any class which inherits NSObject) is `alloc` (or `new` depending on usage). This is why you can call `[UIView alloc]`, as alloc is inherited through the class hierarchy. `UIView` itself doesn't provide an implementation for `alloc`, rather it inherits the method through `NSObject`.

A simple and common example to illustrate inheritance uses animals. Let's say we have a super-class at the root of the hierarchy which all animals inherit from called `Creature`. Now let's subclass `Creature` to create a `Mammal` class. The `Mammal` class will inherit all the functionality (the public interface) of the `Creature class`.

```
@interface Creature{

}
- (void)whatAmI;

@end

@implementation Creature

-(void)whatAmI{

     NSlog(@"I am a Creature");
}

@end

@interface Mammal:Creature{

}

@end
```

Implement our `Mammal` class:

```
Mammal *mammal1 = [[Mammal alloc]init];
[mammal1 whatAmI];
```

**Output:**

> I am a Creature

Note that `Mammal` inherits the `-whoAmI` method from the parent class `Creature`.You can now inherit from `Mammal` and that subclass will inherit both the functionality of `Mammal` and `Creature`. The hierarchy of inheritance can continue.

If you want a firm understanding of Objective-C I recommend ***Programming in Objective-C*** *by Steven Kochan.*

**Resources which discuss inheritance in Objective-C:**

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Inheritance

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_inheritance.htm

[Objective-C multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192203/objective-c-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the use of subclass is to customize the new functionality which can be reuse in other class as well.