# Complex class hierarchies in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, templates, inheritance

Consider the following base classes:

```
@interface ViewBase : UIView
@property (readonly) LayerBase *myLayer;
+ (Class)myLayerClass; // _myLayer = [[[self class] myLayerClass] new];
@end

@interface LayerBase : CALayer
@property AbstractGrid *grid;
@end

class AbstractGrid
{
public:
    int rows, columns;
    virtual someMethod() = 0;
}
```

I have a template `Grid` class that uses different cell types (`AbstractGrid` is needed because it's not possible to create template Objective-C classes):

```
template <class Cell>
class Grid : public AbstractGrid
{
public:
    Cell **cells;
    virtual someMethod() {}
}
```

Now I want to create a subclass of `ViewBase` that has type of `myLayer` also subclass of `LayerBase` (the `+myLayerClass` method is also redefined) and use different template parameter for the model class, for example:

```
@interface AView : ViewBase
@property (readonly) ALayer *myLayer;
@end

@interface ALayer : LayerBase
@property Grid<GridCell> *grid;
@end

class GridCell
{
public:
    int row, column;
}
```

The application works fine with this approach, but compiler gives me warnings about incompatible property types:

> property type 'ALayer *' is incompatible with type 'LayerBase *' inherited from 'ViewBase'
>   property type 'Grid *' is incompatible with type 'AbstractGrid *' inherited from 'LayerBase'

While I can silence the first warning by declaring layer property with type `id` (which isn't the best solution as I can't use dot syntax without type casting, and I may make mistakes which compiler won't be able to catch):

```
@property (readonly) id myLayer;
```

I can't do the same with C++ type. Declaring the `grid` property as `void *` also doesn't help.

So is there a proper way to handle such situation? Or I should simply silence the warnings using pragmas since I know what I'm doing?

Please refrain from advising not to use C++ classes because it's not an option (I'm creating a set of cross-platform model classes to ease porting in future).

Comment: Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365732/how-to-inherit-from-multiple-class
A compounded class may save headaches compared to a multi-intheritance class in obj-c

Comment: I'm not using multiple inheritance, there's aggregation

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Don't alter the return type. For example:

```
@interface LayerBase : CALayer
- (AbstractGrid *)grid;
@end


@interface ALayer : LayerBase

// ALayer's local storage and typed interface:
@property Grid<GridCell>* grid_GridCell; // << use unique selector names

// ALayer's abstract interface/overrides:
- (AbstractGrid *)grid; // << returns self.grid_GridCell

@end
```

Comment: It means creating 'fake' ivars which seems rather stupid to me... Also, it's going to break unified grid access for subclasses. The goal is to make compiler know real class of `grid` property at compile time.

Comment: @kambala if all you need is the interface of `AbstractGrid`, you can expose `AbstractGrid` and use a factory -- without the need for creating objc variants. this is no different from C++; downcasting in both languages requires a cast in both languages for good reason. if you need that type information statically, then you should use properly typed variables anyway, and your `LayerBase` would not hold the ivar. of course, you *could* also accomplish it dynamically using `dynamic_cast<>`. in objc, you should not alter the return type as in your example, for the same reason C++ forbids it.

Comment: Factory doesn't suit in my case because I set `grid` pointers for each   LayerBase subclass from external model object.

Comment: @kambala i understand your objective, but the language designers of both objc and c++ don't want you to have implicit downcasting for a reason, and also why the functions in question have unmatched signatures. if you want this type information, i recommend you preserve it and use templates (not in an objc interface), or `dynamic_cast<>` and `AbstractGrid`. the caveat to your answer is that the compiler doesn't have *all* the information; it only has enough to compile the program…

Comment: @kambala …this means that you will need to always introduce exact type information at the callsite in order to deal with the type, and it will be more difficult the deeper your class hierarchies grow. this becomes a problem because the compiler uses the return type of method of the variable you pass. if the objc type is not the same as declared, you will be holding a pointer to the wrong type. this also leads to ambiguous return types. the compiler may in the future realize what you are doing and call it out -- as your hierarchy grows, or as you include other `LayerBase` subtypes in a TU. (con

Comment: @kambala (cont) it will be hard for you to assume responsibility of layout compatibility. that's why i wrote "use unique selector names". your approach *could* work in a defined manner for class hierarchies with depth restrictions -- but it would be very difficult to use/maintain in complex hierarchies under less specialized hierarchies -- as a *generalized* form, it is unsafe. if anything, you may want to `dynamic_cast<>` the return type to the declared variable type, to detect incompatibilities at runtime, which were not detected at compilation due to type erasure.

Comment: Thank you for a very rich answer. I understand all the risks I'm taking, but the true power of C/C++ is that you may do almost anything you want in the code as long as you know what you're doing :) The `grid` pointer is assigned only once and it's ViewController's responsibility (i.e. completely under my control), so I'm on a safe side here.

Comment: @kambala ok. maybe you have the special case i mentioned, where it is safe. only you have the sources to prove that :) for completeness: in my designs, i just do as much in c++ in this scenario as possible, where type safety may be preserved, and expose only the minimal interface necessary in objc (that may ultimately be none). my codebase does not depend on `dynamic_cast<>`, or even RTTI. that objc interface may not even expose the member, but define a separate abstract interface. (cont)

Comment: @kambala (cont) or that may involve introducing another abstraction layer. in general, i would try to preserve type safety, and minimize what the objc interface exposes (including redundancy) -- iow, i would avoid making really rich objc wrappers of complex c++ types where possible. you're welcome, and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to remove the `grid` @property (since I don't need any property features like KVO in this case) in favor of good old getter/setter and simply cast return type in subclasses. clang is clever enough to allow dot syntax for arbitrary getters, so now I'm getting no warnings.

```
@interface LayerBase : CALayer {
    AbstractGrid *_grid;
}
- (AbstractGrid *)grid;
- (void)setGrid:(AbstractGrid *)grid;
@end

@implementation LayerBase
- (AbstractGrid *)grid {
    return _grid;
}

- (void)setGrid:(AbstractGrid *)grid {
    _grid = grid;
}
@end

@interface ALayer : LayerBase
- (Grid<GridCell> *)grid;
@end

@implementation ALayer
- (Grid<GridCell> *)grid {
    return (Grid<GridCell> *)[super grid];
}
@end
```